# Openpyxl changing the color of the words which is in the list, not the whole cell

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to change the color of the part that contains the words in the `prev_list` to red. Multiple `prev_list` words can come out in one sentence. My code now only changes the color of the last matching word.

Example:

```
I have a dog, a cat and a fish
```

TO-BE:

```
I have a **dog** (redfont), a **cat** and a **fish**
```

AS-IS:

```
I have a dog, a cat and a **fish**
```

Code:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell.text import InlineFont
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import re


prev_words = pd.read_excel("prev_file.xlsx", usecols=['word'])
prev_list = prev_words['word'].tolist()

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
df = pd.read_excel("new_file.xlsx")

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

red = InlineFont(color='00FF0000')
black = InlineFont(color='00000000')

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=0):
    for cell in row:
        cell_value = str(cell.value)
        rich_text = CellRichText()

        contains_prev_word = False
        for word in prev_list:
            if word in cell_value:
                contains_prev_word = True
                break

        if not contains_prev_word:
            rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, cell_value))
        else:
            for match in re.finditer(word, cell_value):
                start_idx = match.start()
                end_idx = start_idx + len(word)
                rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, cell_value[:start_idx]))
                rich_text.append(TextBlock(red, cell_value[start_idx:end_idx]))
                rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, cell_value[end_idx:]))
        cell.value = rich_text

wb.save("resultresult2.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. As far as I can see it will highlight a word from  prev_file.xlsx where found in a row in new_file.xlsx, but **only one of the words per row**. But what you have and expect is unclear.

Comment: Hello, the expected effect I want is to highlight all the words that match the prev_list in the cell-by-cell sentences in the new_file. There are several sentences in the cell-by-cell within the new_file, and the prev_file is a list of words.

Comment: So if a row in the Sheet in 'new_file.xlsx' has:- *a pear, a dog, a cat, a fish, a car, a truck, a bus, a dog, a pear, an apple, a car, a peach* and the the list 'prev_list' contains 'dog', 'pear' and 'car', you want **every** instance of those three words appearing in that sentence highlighted in Red?

Comment: yes right! every instance of those three words appearing in the sentence should be highlighted expectation: - a "pear", a "dog", a cat, a fish, a car, a truck, a bus, a "dog", a pear, an apple, a "car", a peach

Comment: As noted in the duplicate of this question, Pandas isn't necessary here at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    for cell in row:
        if not cell.value: 
            continue    # skip if empty
        msg = str(cell.value)
        red_spans = sorted((s.start(), s.end()) 
                           for word in {*prev_list} 
                           for s in re.finditer(rf'\b{word}\b', msg))
        if not red_spans: 
            continue    # skip if nothing found
        rich_text = CellRichText()
        prev = 0        # prev is the right end of the previous red span
        for left, right in red_spans:
            if prev < left:
                rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, msg[prev:left]))
            rich_text.append(TextBlock(red, msg[left:right]))
            prev = right
        if prev < len(msg):
            rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, msg[prev:]))
        cell.value = rich_text
```

#### Notes

1. To skip headers we have to pass `min_row=2` or `min_row=1+df.columns.nlevels` because of 1-based index in Excel.
2. We might be interested to skip processing of empty cells to avoid filling them with `"None"`.
3. It may be better to wrap the words you are looking for with `'\\b'`, which [matches the empty strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) at the beginning or end of them.
4. We can be sure that intervals in `red_spans` do not overlap because of wrapping unique words with `\\b`.

Comment: nice implementation

Comment: You can reduce loops by joining the search terms with `|`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess the requirement is something similar to this
where a row in 'new_file.xlsx' contains words to be highlighted in RED in a sentence like shown. 
[image: Input Data]

As an example, the words in the 'prev_file.xlsx' as extracted into 'prev_list' are;
[image]

This method creates a list of lists where the RED highlighting needs to occur.
The list looks like this;
[[10, 3], [55, 3], [2, 4], [62, 4], [32, 3], [80, 3]]

The first element of each individual list is the index where the RED highlight starts and the second element is the length of the word to highlight.
The list is sorted to allow the textblocks to be applied sequentially to the cell text, resulting in a list like so;
[[2, 4], [10, 3], [32, 3], [55, 3], [62, 4], [80, 3]]

Then just loop through this list and apply each as a text block in the cell text leaving the intermediary text as black.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell.text import InlineFont
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import re


prev_words = pd.read_excel("prev_file.xlsx", usecols=['word'])
prev_list = prev_words['word'].tolist()

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
df = pd.read_excel("new_file.xlsx")

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

red = InlineFont(color='00FF0000')
black = InlineFont(color='00000000')

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell_value = str(cell.value)
        rich_text = CellRichText()

        wd_positions_list = []
        ### Create list of lists for RED highlight positions
        for word in prev_list:
            pattern = fr"(?:^|\b){word}(?:$|\b)"  # Change search to a pattern
            if word in cell_value:
                for match in re.finditer(pattern, cell_value):
                    wd_positions_list.append([match.start(), len(word)])

        if wd_positions_list:  # If the list has values process them
            wd_positions_list = sorted(wd_positions_list)  # Sort the list by the first element in each list of lists

            blk_start_idx = 0  # Black text start index
            for word_position in wd_positions_list:
                start_idx = word_position[0]
                word_length = word_position[1]

                end_idx = start_idx + word_length

                if start_idx > 0:  # Dont create a black text block if first block is red
                    rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, cell_value[blk_start_idx:start_idx]))

                rich_text.append(TextBlock(red, cell_value[start_idx:end_idx]))
                blk_start_idx = end_idx

            rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, cell_value[blk_start_idx:]))  # add any remaining text as black
            cell.value = rich_text

wb.save("result2.xlsx")
```

Resulting text
For search words;
['apple', 'applepie', 'dog', 'duck', 'pear', 'car']
[image: result2.xlsx]

**Note** some comments regarding your code;
Openpyxl rows start at 1 so the 'min_row' in `ws.iter_rows(min_row=0)` is incorrect but also unnecessary. Openpyxl code will auto fix this to 1 however since 1 is the default for min values it's not required to specify anyway. 
 This line will do the same thing `ws.iter_rows():`

The `wb.close()` command only has affect if you open the XLSX file as read-only or write-only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think there's an issue. Could you look at it if you don't mind? Issue: The matching word doesn't highlight in red when it comes to the first part of the sentence. (example: pear, a dog, a cat, a fish > matching words doesn't highlight in red)

Comment: Updated the code; Forgot the line to append any remaining text to the end of the line. Also added a check in case a RED highlight word starts at 0. Try it again

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well in most cases. Is it okay to ask if you can correct me to add some red letters based on the longest word when some of the prev_file words are matched....?

Comment: You can ask but the question is not clear, most likely you can do what you want but I don't know what exactly you are asking. However it is preferable if you have another question to create a new question so you have the space to fully explain what you are attempting to achieve, with data and screen shots if required and not trying to cram the requirements into a comment window. It's free to ask questions and everybody can help answer.

Comment: I've posted a new related question. Could you check it if you don't mind?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031872/openpyxl-when-multiple-words-match-display-the-longest-word-in-red

Comment: I've updated the code to search for whole word only to fix the 'apple'  'applepie' issue. see 'Resulting Text' for the prev_list used. You can see if that works any better for your requirements.