# Openpyxl when multiple words match, display the longest word in red (Document language =kr, cn)

Tags: python, openpyxl

The code below highlights the specified words in English texts, but does not work correctly when switching to Korean or Chinese. Is there any way to solve this problem?

For example, with the following specified words and a message in Korean:

```
prev_list = ['사과', '사과파이']
msg = '강아지고양이사과그리고사과파이아왜안됨'
```

the final highlighting should look like this:

강아지고양이**사과**그리고**사과파이**아왜안됨

Note that in this case, using the `'\b'` pattern to search for a word makes no sense.

```
#stackoverflow
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell.text import InlineFont
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import re


prev_words = pd.read_excel("prev_file1.xlsx", usecols=['word'])
prev_list = prev_words['word'].tolist()

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
df = pd.read_excel("new_file1.xlsx")

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

red = InlineFont(color='00FF0000')
black = InlineFont(color='00000000')

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1):
    for cell in row:
        if not cell.value: 
            continue    # skip if empty
        msg = str(cell.value)
        red_spans = sorted((s.start(), s.end()) 
                           for word in {*prev_list} 
                           for s in re.finditer(rf'\b{word}\b', msg))
        if not red_spans: 
            continue    # skip if nothing found
        rich_text = CellRichText()
        prev = 0        # prev is the right end of the previous red span
        for left, right in red_spans:
            if prev < left:
                rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, msg[prev:left]))
            rich_text.append(TextBlock(red, msg[left:right]))
            prev = right
        if prev < len(msg):
            rich_text.append(TextBlock(black, msg[prev:]))
        cell.value = rich_text      

wb.save("result1.xlsx")
```

Comment: This code could be simplified a lot. Start by taking Pandas comptelely out of it because you're only working with XLSX files. But the main thing is to provide a clearer example of what you're trying to achieve based on the values in a couple of cells. You can then work on the code necessary for this and only then on how to use in a worksheet.

Comment: @moken if it has 'orange, applepie, a car', the result of the code is like: 'orange, **appleapplepie**, a car' ('apple' and 'applepie' both are added to the text). expectation:   'orange, **applepie**, a car' ( add and highlight the 'applepie' only)

Comment: @moken If prev_list = ['apple', 'applepie'], AS-IS: **appleapplepie**, **apple**, TO-BE: **apple**, **applepie**

Comment: My apologies, I understand now. I though this was a different question about highlighting words based on their size. But I see it's just a different input for the same implementation that is causing the appleapplepie in the output. So I suggest you use @Vitalizzare's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78021517/13664137) as this will not overlap the words and should highlight without running the two words together. Just change the code from `for row in ws.iter_rows():` for the solution they posted. They start their rows at row 2 so just remove the `min_row=2` to start at row 1.

Comment: Asking the same question repeatedly is not very friendly.

Comment: @CharlieClark It's not the same question

Comment: @moken Thank you for your comment! I tried the code and it works well in English but it doesn't seem to work well in Korean and Chinese documents... Is there a code that can be applied to sentences with no spaces? If you don't mind, would it be okay if I ask you to check? Except for the matching issue, your solution code worked well. If prev_list = ['사과', '사과파이'], TO-BE: 강아지고양이**사과**그리고**사과파이**아왜안됨

Comment: @EveShin How do you separate words in your language? For example, we can look for the word _chrome_ in the text _inch rome_, and without the space we couldn't define if it's _in chrome_ or something else.

Comment: @Vitalizzare Hi! Thank you for answering. In the case of Chinese, there are no spaces, the word units are distinguished by the meaning.
Example:  prev_list=['苹果'， '苹果派'] TO-BE: 小狗，小猫和**苹果**还有**苹果派**

Comment: @EveShin It's hard to answer without knowing the language. For example, if `msg = "사과파이"` and 사과파이 is a single word (not a phrase) while `prev_list = ['사과']` then would it be a mistake to mark it up as **사과**파이? Another possible issue, what if you have single words meaning e.g. "big apple" and "apple pie" while the message is "big apple pie", which part of it should be highlighted?

Comment: @Vitalizzare If msg = "사과파이", prev_list = ['사과'], mark it up as **사과**파이 = correct.  If msg = "큰사과파이(big apple pie)", prev_list = ['큰사과', '사과파이'], the result should be "큰**사과파이**" (highlight the longest matched word in the list in red).

Comment: The question is closed and discussions like this should be continued elsewhere.

Comment: Here's the problem as I can see it. Let's say `prev_list = ['ABCDEFGH', 'FGHIJK', 'JKLM']; msg = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'` (I'm not sure if it's possible, but imagine that it's not Latin but Korean characters). What do you expect as a result in this case?

Comment: @Vitalizzare  In the case of prev_list = ['ABCDEFGH', 'FGHIJK', 'JKLM']; msg = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM', the result should be "**ABCDEFGH**IJKLM"!